# Expression for Calculating a RunningValue column in SSRS Tablix Control

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

User enters a fixed parameter representing a Credit Limit.
Then each row subtracts a different column called [AmountPaid].
So the Balance Available column show what is left and this gets smaller and smaller down the rows to the bottom.

Both column textboxes in Tablix are set to Number type=Currency. Parameter is set to Float. Not many choices of data type for the Parameter input.

I thought this would work in an expression for the Balance Available but it gives me an error. My idea was to do a running Sum and then subtract it from the initial Credit Limit:

=Parameters!CreditLimit.Value - RunningValue(Fields!AmountPaid, Sum, "DataSet1")

The message for the error is:
    [rsAggregateOfInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox23.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function with an expression that returned a data type not valid for the aggregate function.

If this question could be asked differently I am open to suggestions. Thanks

Comment: You need to get the value of AmountPaid so try `Fields!AmountPaid.Value`

Comment: You're very welcome, sometimes you can't see the problems right in front of you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value of AmountPaid so try Fields!AmountPaid.Value`

Comment: Oh! Thank you Alan! If it was a snake it would have bit me. In my past life I was an Access programmer and I could leave off .Value because it was the default. You made my day! Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it. thank you again